# Prefixing multiple values within QGIS using the Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a column in my my attribute table that contains a series of **individually** numbered locations. I wish to prefix all of these numbers with a letter, this letter will be the same for each of the values. E.g. 100, 200 and 300 would become A100, A200 and A300. I have a lot of data so simply going through and renaming would take a lot of time.

I have a feeling this would be achieved through the Field Calculator but unsure of which expression would be best for this?

Comment: Well Joshua, take your pick :). All answers should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
'A' ||  "column name"
```

in a new field of type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
concat('A', "your_column" )
```

Note: Your column must accept **Strings** so if your current column type is set to integer, you will have to create a new field in the Field Calculator and set it to String.

Answer (score 1):

The expression would be, for example:

```
'A'  ||  "someField"
```

*someField* would be your field that you want to use when updating and || is used to concatenate strings in QGIS.

**EDIT**:
Make sure the values are put in between single quotes and the field names are put in between double quotes!